# Maximum Data transmission & PCI slot in GIGABYTE Z390 UD

Tags: motherboard, data-transfer, pci

I am using a frame grabber installed on a [GIGABYTE Z390 UD](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-UD-rev-10#kf).

For maximum "100%" data transmission the frame grabber documentation recommends installing it in an X8 PCIe slot with base specification 2.x . I am confused with the annotations on the motherboard.

Can you please help choose which slot to use for installation in GIGABYTE Z390 UD?

Edit :

this annotation confuses me :

GIGABYTE Z390 UD has :

(1x PCI-E 3.0 x16 @ x16)
(2x PCI-E 3.0 x16 @ x4)
(3x PCI-E 3.0 x1 @ x1)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please help choose which slot to use for installation in GIGABYTE Z390 UD?

Your motherboard does not actually have a PCI-E 3.0 x8 slot.  It has one full x16 bandwidth **PCI-E 3.0 x16** slot and two 1/4 x16 bandwidth **PCI-E 3.0 x16** slots (i.e. `PCI-E 3.0 x16 @x4`).  The purpose of the x16 slots is to support full-length PCI-E cards.  **I suspect the reason they are 1/4 bandwidth slots is due to the fact the motherboard is marketed to users with multiple GPUs.**

1/4 of the bandwidth of a PCIEx16 slot (**15.75 GB/s**) is **3.94 GB/sec**

If you want you the frame grabber, to have the full bandwidth of a `PCI-E 3.0 x8` (7.88 GB/s) slot, you will have to put it in the slot labeled **PCIEX16**.

```
It means the PCI-E lane uses a quarter of the full bandwidth of a PCI-E lane. The full length of bandwidth for the slot would be x16. There's also an x8 spec that runs half the bandwidth.
```

Related: [What does PCIe 2.0 x16 (x4 mode) mean?](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/54864-what-does-pcie-20-x16-x4-mode-mean/)